# Azure usual download URL for latest no longer working

Tags: visual-studio-code, download

https://vscode-update.azurewebsites.net/latest/linux-deb-x64/stable

I used to get the updates from here, has it changed to somewhere else?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you download Visual Studio Code from https://code.visualstudio.com with the configuration you specified, they offer you this direct link:

https://code.visualstudio.com/sha/download?build=stable&os=linux-deb-x64